# Android Notification Sound not from /res

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app that gets audio files from Firebase, saves them on the device, then uses that audio file as the notification sound.

I can't get the audio file to play as the notification sound.

It seems like Android only wants sounds stored in the Resources (/res) folder. Conversely, it seems like you can't programmatically add files to the /res folder.

Would appreciate some clarification on the best way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MediaPlayer` and then `setDataSource(String path)` and pass it a file path. Because the media subsystem runs in a different, non-privileged process the path needs to be to a world-readable file (e.g., on external storage). For example, you could dump the file somewhere under [`Context.getExternalFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)).

EDIT: to actually attempt to answer the question about notifications.

The `Notification.Builder.setSound()` method accepts a URI, but it doesn't say what kind of URI. If you follow the code into the platform in `NotificationManagerService`, it uses `IRingtonPlayer` to play the sound (that interface is not in the public SDK). That eventually uses another class / method: `Rintone.play()`. From what I can tell, `Ringtone` just wraps a `MediaPlayer`.

So to make a long story short, you should be able to call `setSound()` with a world-readable file URI like:

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("file://" + filePath.getAbsolutePath());
builder.setSound(uri, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffery! What would I then pass to `notification.setSound(...)`?

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm logging the URI as "/data/user/0/com.[appPackage]/files/Sounds/[fileName]" however the sound doesn't play when the notification is triggered, I only get a vibration. I did verify that I can play the default notification sound.

Comment: A long shot but you might try prefixing with "file://".

Comment: Progress: now instead of playing nothing, it plays the default sound.

Comment: Is my path correct, or should it start from '/Sounds/...'?

Comment: I don't know it depends on where you stored your sound file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172785/discussion-between-davids-1-and-jeffrey-blattman).

Comment: @davids.1 did you found any solution, cause I am stuck in the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need.

```
Uri tone = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.notification);
//notification refers to the file name of your mp3 file
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
       .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
       .setContentTitle("Title")
       .setContentText("Message")
       .setSound(tone);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to play a custom sound, not the default sound.

Comment: Appreciate the edit. The file I have isn't in the resources folder. It is under '[packageName]/files/'